# How many Zs are there?

Tags: project-zomboid

I started a PZ map turning off the undead respawn, but set the helicopter to recurring on an otherwise *standard* ("Apocalypse") setup of the "custom Sandbox" (as in, the one it proposes when opening). Now, I have holed myself up in Louisville Gigamart and spent about... two months or some culling  1500 and some ex-living. Whenever the Helicopter returns, the streets are crawling again and I need to clean my proximity again and again. Luckily spear raw materials grow back but I might run out of axes and knives some day...

### Settings

The standard settings referred to are as follows, bolded where I changed something:

- Population: Standard & Urban Focussed
- Time: 1h / July 9th 9AM
- Sadistic AI Director: Helicopter **Often** / Meta Sometimes / Sleeping Events never
- Zombie Lore: Proper Zombies is hooked
- Advanced Zombie Options:

  - Population Multiplier: 1.0
  - Population Start Multiplier: 1.0
  - Population Peak Multiplier: 1.5
  - Population Peak Day: 25
  - Respawn Hours: **0**
  - Respawn Unseen Hours: **0**
  - Respawn Multiplier: **0**
  - Redistribute Hours: 12.0
  - Follow Sound Distance: 100
  - Rally Group Size: 20
  - Rally Travel Distance: 20
  - Rally Group Separation: 15
  - Rally Group Radius: 3

### Question

How high will my kill count be when I have slain the last Z?

Comment: What other settings (like peak population day) are you playing on as that can change things. (Besides turning off respawn).

Comment: @n_plum besides the two changes (to four settings) that should fully disable **any** respawn and to get the helicopter to draw them in, no changes to Apocalypse were made, no mods are installed.

Comment: A note about respawn: Just make sure you set your peak day to a low number

It basically locks the population to whatever the zed pop was when you first entered it, so if you don't have your peak day very low it'll lock your starting areas to a tiny population while the rest of the map will have a normal amount of zeds provided you don't visit other areas before the peak day. (Granted you clear your starting area)

Comment: You mean I did incidentally cut the population of Zs by only removing the ability to respawn and I may have less than the amount you quoted? I had to get to Louisville from Westpoint anyway...

Comment: If respawn is off, and you clear out your spawn area (riverside etc), before the 'population peak' is hit, they will "lock" your area and they won't reach their peak because of respawn issues. That's apparently where the reddit thread came from. If you have high migration and stuff it may negate that as they'll travel around in groups

Comment: so... the best guess is, that I might have lost a couple (hundred?) Zs, but the ballpark is still "50k+" or something?

Comment: If you managed to clear your entire surrounding/starting area, you may lose out on a few, but you can expect 50K plus in total to my understanding. Especially given the size of Louisville. That likely has over 5000 easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fairly [in-depth analysis someone on Reddit did](https://www.reddit.com/r/projectzomboid/comments/ojcoc6/analyzing_the_zed_population/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share) a little bit ago (includes a heatmap picture), but the numbers should be the same for the noted locations.

**Note:** Louisville was added recently and does not have stats referenced here. It's the biggest city addition to the game in recent years and likely has over 5000 as it's bigger than west point. But I cannot say for sure nor have I seen a heatmap done on it yet.

> To summarize the points related to your question:
>
> - Main Riverside: around 1500 zeds.
> - Trailer neighborhood of Riverside: around 600 zeds.
> - Country Club: around 500-700 zeds.
> - Ekron: around 800 zeds.
> - Pony Roam-o: 300 zeds.
> - Isolated cabins and houses in the west of the game: 3800 zeds.
> - Rosewood + Prison: 5500.
> - Secret military base: 5000.
> - March Ridge: 2400.
> - Muldraugh: 4000.
> - Dixie: 350.
> - West Point: 5000.
> - Valley Station: 4500
> - The Mall: 4000.
>
> Total of zeds in the map: 52000. [Not including Louisville]
>
> Changing the population multiplier multiplies the number of in-game zeds. If you choose 0.5, then the total will be around 26000.

Answer (score 1):

According to the the Project Zomboid wiki, Louisville has an estimated 280,000 zombies as shown here: https://pzwiki.net/wiki/Louisville,_KY

That would be 280,000 + 52,000 bringing the grand estimated total to 332,000 zombies!

Comment: The wiki says ca 22000